# Deleting columns of data frames according to a condition in a list-R

Tags: r

I have a list(list1) which consists of data frames(df1,df2..,dfn). Each data consists factor(f1, f2,..) and numeric(n1,n2,...) variables. For example let:

```
list1[[1]]:

df1:

f1   f2   f3   n1   n2
---  ---  ---  ---  ---
a    c    x    12   5
a    c    x    5    65
a    c    y    21   90
b    a    x    45   6
b    a    x    33   11
a    a    y    5    39
a    a    y    73   22

list1[[2]]:

df2:

f4   f5   n1   n2   n3
---  ---  ---  ---  ---
d    c    12   5    41
d    b    5    65   14
d    c    21   90   51
a    a    45   6    85
d    a    33   11   7
a    a    5    39   1
a    a    73   22   16
```

Desired output is list2

```
list2[[1]]:

df1:

f2   f3   n1   n2
---  ---  ---  ---
c    x    12   5
c    x    5    65
c    y    21   90
a    x    45   6
a    x    33   11
a    y    5    39
a    y    73   22

list2[[2]]:

df2:

f4   n1   n2   n3
---  ---  ---  ---
d    12   5    41
d    5    65   14
d    21   90   51
a    45   6    85
d    33   11   7
a    5    39   1
a    73   22   16
```

Namely, if a factor column have less than 3 observation that column will be deleted. For the above example

- `list1$df1$f1` have 2 "b" observations which is less than 3. So it f1 will be deleted at the output
- `list1$df2$f5` have 1 "b" and 2 "c" observations which are less than 3. So it f5 will be deleted at the output.

How can I do that using R? I will be very gald for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
lapply(list1, function(df) df[, sapply(df, function(x) is.numeric(x) | (is.factor(x) && min(table(x))>=3))])
```

It applies along your list, this function, which returns only numeric columns or factors with at least 3 for all levels:

```
df1[, sapply(df1, function(x) is.numeric(x) | (is.factor(x) && min(table(x))>=3))]
```

---

To recreate `list1`, here is a `dput` of it:

```
  list1 <- 
  list(structure(list(f1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
  1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), f2 = structure(c(2L, 
  2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "c"), class = "factor"), 
      f3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", 
      "y"), class = "factor"), n1 = c(12L, 5L, 21L, 45L, 33L, 5L, 
      73L), n2 = c(5L, 65L, 90L, 6L, 11L, 39L, 22L)), .Names = c("f1", 
  "f2", "f3", "n1", "n2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -7L)), structure(list(f4 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
  1L), .Label = c("a", "d"), class = "factor"), f5 = structure(c(3L, 
  2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
      n1 = c(12L, 5L, 21L, 45L, 33L, 5L, 73L), n2 = c(5L, 65L, 
      90L, 6L, 11L, 39L, 22L), n3 = c(41L, 14L, 51L, 85L, 7L, 1L, 
      16L)), .Names = c("f4", "f5", "n1", "n2", "n3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -7L)))
```